# this discord.js event doesn't work needs adaptation

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was wanting to adapt this code to work within my discord.js bot project.

As an event, it starts as soon as the bot comes online, but this way it isn't coming online, not even a console.log returns a log about that event.

this code below would have to run inside this event code.

and all my events start from a:

```
client.on("ready", () => { // event of my project starts like this
// code
});
```

````
module.exports = class {
  constructor(client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  async run() {
    this.client.on("ready", async () => {
      await this.VipFilter();
    });
  }
  async VipFilter() {
    setInterval(async () => {
      const list_vips = await require("mongoose")
        .connection.collection("users")
        .find({ "vip.date": { $gt: 1 } })
        .toArray();

      const filter_members = Object.entries(list_vips).filter(
        ([, x]) => x.vip.date <= Date.now()
      );

      const VIPS = filter_members.map(([, x]) => x.idU);

      await this.VipRemove(VIPS);
    }, 60000);
  }

  async VipRemove(VIPS) {
    let totalPessoas = VIPS.length;
    let size = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      if (totalPessoas <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
      else {
        let members = VIPS[size++];

        const user = await this.client.users.fetch(members);

        await this.client.database.users.findOneAndUpdate(
          { idU: user.id },
          { $set: { "vip.date": 0, "vip.hasVip": false } }
        );
      }

      totalPessoas--;
    }, 5000);
  }
}; ```
````

Comment: which file is second block code is from . Is it your execute.js file

Comment: @HellCatVN The biggest code is an event that doesn't load in my bot, I think because it is with module.exports = class..

all my bot events start with

client.on("ready", () => { // event of my project starts like this
// code
});

my bot's executable is bot.js

Comment: what is your bot.js look like do it import the export ?

Comment: @HellCatVN No, it doesn't import the export, that's why I want to adapt this code.

my bot.js is like that

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
});
```
and events are like that

```
const { client } = require('../bot.js');

client.on("ready", () => { // event of my project starts like this
// code
});
```